# USB flash drive stuck in read only mode after stopping copy of macOS Mojave to it midway

Tags: macos, usb-flash-drive, hardware-failure, formatting

I was creating a boot for macOS Mojave on my USB flash drive. The transfer of OS the transfer stopped suddenly,  I waited for a few minutes and then ejected it.

After this when I reinserted I was unable to format it, it went to read-only mode. Currently, it's in ExFat Format.

I have tried formatting it in Disk Utility even in the terminal and it didn’t work.

I tried with this command:

```
diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ Backup /dev/disk2
```

[image: Screenshot of the info for the USB flash drive]

Comment: This line confuses me: “The transfer of OS halted and I ejected the USB flash drive in the middle.” So did the transfer suddenly stop and then you ejected it? Or something else.

Comment: Yes, the transfer stopped suddenly. I waited for a few minutes and then ejected it.

Comment: Sad to say that most likely the USB flash drive itself is dead.